# How to burn timestamp in video with different date format using FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor

I am using below command to add timestamps to video:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=roboto.ttf:fontsize=36:fontcolor=yellow:text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1456007118}'" -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

command is working but i don't get desired output. it is adding timestamp like this:

[image: sample video screenshot]

I want to use different date format like this:

1. [Simple Date Format](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#examples)
2. [Date and Time Patterns](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat#date-and-time-patterns)

I get this date :

```
2016-02-20 22:25:20
```

but i want this :

```
Sat, 20 Feb 2016 22:25:20 -0700
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found my answer in this link:

[strftime - format date and time](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)

[strftime(3) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime)

ex: i use this command for demo and i made several other command for different date format

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=roboto.ttf:fontsize=36:fontcolor=yellow:text='%{pts\:gmtime\:1575526882\:%A, %d, %B %Y %I\\\:%M\\\:%S %p}'" -preset ultrafast -f mp4 output.mp4
```